# html email with reference to an image as base64 String

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I would like to send an email with the Java Mail API (*javax.mail*). The message must contain html and inside there is a reference to an image. There is a challenge, because no reference to a physical file on disk is allowed but instead I have created a *base64* string (http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php) for that image and copied that data to a static String variable.
With *javax.mail* I build a message of type *MulitPart* with two parts. The first part is the html itself and the second part is the image. The html part reference to the image via `<img src="cid:image-id"/>.`

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent("<html><body><h2>A title</h2>Some text in here<br/>" +
                "<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/><br/> some more text<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/></body></html>", "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

public static final String base64logo = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QBe…"; // ein ganz langer String erzeugt über http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php

sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64logo);
InternetHeaders header = new InternetHeaders();
BodyPart imgPart=new MimeBodyPart(header, imageByte);
imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID","the-img-1");
imgPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);
```

Unfortunately the image is missing in the incoming email.

When I point to the file on my disk it is working:

```
DataSource ds=new FileDataSource("c:/temp/image001.jpg");
imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
```

We are developing with Talend and we cannot reference
to external files because that would make the deployment process
more complicate.

Can you find some wrong doings in my approach?

Kind regards
Hilderich

Comment: The general approach is correct. I suspect there is something wrong with the image reference. Check out the *full* source of the mail you sent. The image should be in there, check that the id by which you referenced it is correct.

Comment: Thank you! However the reference (Content-ID) is correct spelled.

Comment: I have a same issue , do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked before a long time ago. But I will answer this as I have faced the same issue, from my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373453/java-cannot-send-email-with-html-with-images/44375825#44375825).

```
byte[] tile = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64logo);
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(tile, "image/jpeg"));
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<the-img-1>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting angle braces here

```
imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<the-img-1>");
```

I found this answer on the comments of an old post from this blog

http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/javamail_sending_embedded_image_in

In the comment of Aravind Velayudhan Nair

It worked for me!