# Java cannot send email with html with images

Tags: java, gmail, base64, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email with html which has two images. The two images are sent from the AngularJS client side as base64 strings and looks like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAALuCAYAAAA9jTxNAAAgAElEQ
```

Note that I have truncated the base64 string as its too long.

```
String temp = baseString.split(",")[1];
byte[] tile = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(temp);

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tile);
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new InputStreamDataSource(inputStream));
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

The InputStreamDataSource:

```
public class InputStreamDataSource implements DataSource {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public InputStreamDataSource(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return "*/*";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "InputStreamDataSource";
    }
}
```

The image does not show up in the mail.

But it works perfectly fine when I use a `FileDataSource` instead of base64 string:

```
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("D:\\Projects\\Extras\\sofa1.png");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

This works fine and shows the images.

Someone please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) instead of your own InputStreamDataSource.

Your code only shows one image; hopefully you're using different Content-IDs for each image.

Your code also doesn't should how the html content is referencing the images; hopefully it's using the correct "cid:" URL.

The JavaMail FAQ has more information on [how to send messages that include images](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr).

Comment: Thank you so much, Everyting else is fine like different content id etc I have been trying for quite a long time, I can't believe that its working with ByteArrayDataSource. I did `DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(tile, "image/*"));`

Comment: You **really** want to use a correct image MIME type, e.g., image/gif or image/jpeg, not image/*, which is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: At best, you've been lucky, and whatever mail reader you're using for testing is working around your mistake and ignoring the bad MIME type.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that, I will change it accordingly. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Based on your data above, it should be image/png.

Comment: Yes I have changed that to image/png

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue. I have fixed it using @Bill Shannon's answer. This will set the image src using the base64 string in the html email.

```
String temp = base64String.split(",")[1];
byte[] tile = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(temp);
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(tile, "image/png"));
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

The html string is something like:

```
"<img style=\"height: 100px; width: 100px;\" src=\"cid:image\" alt=\"Tile\" title=\"Tile\">\r\n"
```